# Mysql inner join twice and use WHERE on both joins

Tags: mysql, inner-join

In MySQL, I want to `SELECT A.* FROM A` where an inner join condition is satisfied whether directly (joining table `B`) **or** through another join table (`C`), `WHERE B.field = myvalue`. Can anyone point out the proper way to get results?

I have the following tables: A, B, C, which are associated as follows (A joins B, B joins C, A joins C):

```
      B
    /   \
   A --- C
```

It looks pretty straightforward, but I get an empty set when I run the following code, even though I get results when I restrict the search to just joining B through C:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A
INNER JOIN C ON C.id = A.c_id
INNER JOIN B AS B_thru_C ON B_thru_C.id = C.b_id
INNER JOIN B AS B_from_A ON B_from_A.id = A.b_id
WHERE B_thru_C.field = 'myvalue' OR B_from_A.field = 'myvalue';
# yields an empty set

SELECT A.* FROM A
INNER JOIN C ON C.id = A.c_id
INNER JOIN B AS B_thru_C ON B_thru_C.id = C.b_id
WHERE B_thru_C.field = 'myvalue';
# yields results
```

Comment: Should the query return the records from set A even if there is no successful join to B or C? Or should it eliminate them as well in that scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT A.* FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON C.id = A.c_id
INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.b_id OR B.id = C.b_id
WHERE B.field = 'myvalue';
```

Comment: This will elimnate all records from the result set if the join predicate is not met for B. It' unclear at this point if that matters to the OP or not.

Comment: That's good. I only want records where the join condition is met.